# Partial object returned when Serializing a model with relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have two models `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` has a one to many relationship with `Bar` as shown below.

**app/models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sourceid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, null=True)
    url = models.TextField(unique=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow,null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'foo'

    class JSONAPIMeta:
        resource_name = 'foo'

class Bar(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    parent_foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='parentId')  # Field name made lowercase.
    url = models.TextField()
    extension = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='extensionId', blank=True, null=True) 
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'bar'
```

Now the issue is that I want to create a serializer `FooBarList` that nests `Bar`s into `Foo`.

I have managed to slightly achieve this with the following code:

**app/serializers.py**

```
class FooBarList(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id','name','url','created_at','updated_at','bar_set')
```

When I call this serialise function the issue arrises... Only the 'id' parameter of the `Bar` object is shown in the response. This is shown below:

**JSON Output**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "created_at": "2017-08-23T16:07:11.384209Z",
            "name": "TestFoo",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-23T17:41:17.179040Z",
            "url": "TestFoo.org"
        },
        "id": "1",
        "relationships": {
            "Bar": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "Bar"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "type": "Bar"
                    },
                ],
                "meta": {
                    "count": 2
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "Foo"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "created_at": "2017-08-23T16:07:11.390343Z",
            "name": "TestFoo2",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-23T17:41:17.186193Z",
            "url": "TestFoo2.org"
        },
        "id": "2",
        "relationships": {
            "Bar": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "10",
                        "type": "Bar"
                    }
                ],
                "meta": {
                    "count": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "type":"Foo"
    }]}
```

From looking in the database I can see that the IDs are correct howver I would have thought that this should include the other attributes from the `Bar` object such as 'url'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Create a serializer for `Bar` and provide it in `FooBarList` serializer.

```
class FooBarList(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   bar = BarSerializer(source='bar')
```

So the related `Bar` instance can be serialized

Comment: Sadly this hasn't changed the response and it still only contains the 'ID'

Comment: could you post your exact serialized data. the `JSON Output` in the post seems not relevant .